# No Author in SVN Repo Logs

Tags: svn, repository, apache, redmine

I'm trying to set up an svn repository and Redmine on a new box.  Everything is up and running fine, except that I'd like to force a author upon a commit.

Right now, my logs look like this (svn log):

`r10 | (no author) | 2015-04-30 16:18:47 -0700 (Thu, 30 Apr 2015) | 2 lines`

We have another box that has been set up with svn since I've been here, and it asks the user for his username and password every time one tries to commit.  I've looked through all the config files, and they look exactly the same.  How can I accomplish this?  I've posted this question to Stackoverflow and the Redmine forums.  I've yet to get an answer.  This is a very very big deal to me as I'd like to see who committed what to the repo.

Here's my apache2.conf for the svn directory.  There's a lot of Redmine stuff in it, but I don't think it matters.  I think Redmine just looks at the author on the the svn stuff to display it.

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/redmine-svn
    Options FollowSymLinks
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy any

    # If a client tries to svn update which involves updating many files,
    # the update request might result in an error Server sent unexpected
    # return value (413 Request  Entity Too Large) in response to REPORT
    # request,because the size of the update request exceeds the limit
    # allowed by the server. You can avoid this error by disabling the
    # request size limit by adding the line LimitXMLRequestBody 0
    # between the <Location...> and </Location> lines. 
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0

    # Only check Authentication for root path, nor again for recursive
    # folder.
    # Redmine core does only permit access on repository level, so this
    # doesn't hurt security. On the other hand it does boost performance
    # a lot!
    SVNPathAuthz on

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine SVN Repository"

    #read-only access    
    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            Require valid-user
            Allow from localhost
            # Allow from another-ip
            Satisfy any
    </Limit>

    # write access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            #Require all denied
            Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>

    ## for mysql
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_default;host=localhost"

    RedmineDbUser "redmine"
    RedmineDbPass "---"

</Location>
```

In /etc/subversion/config on the server, I have uncommented the following:

`store-passwords = no`

`store-auth-creds = no`

I then delete my local stuff in .subversion/auth/* on my client.  But I can still commit without supplying an author!  I think the problem lies in the Apache stuff, but I just can't figure it out :(

What am I missing?  This is driving me up the walls, and I can't proceed forward with having these authorless commits!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated apache.conf seems to ask me my password for my user (changes in bold):

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/redmine-svn
    Options FollowSymLinks
    **Order deny,allow**
    #Deny from all
    **#Require valid-user**
    Satisfy any

    # If a client tries to svn update which involves updating many files,
    # the update request might result in an error Server sent unexpected
    # return value (413 Request  Entity Too Large) in response to REPORT
    # request,because the size of the update request exceeds the limit
    # allowed by the server. You can avoid this error by disabling the
    # request size limit by adding the line LimitXMLRequestBody 0
    # between the <Location...> and </Location> lines. 
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0

    # Only check Authentication for root path, nor again for recursive
    # folder.
    # Redmine core does only permit access on repository level, so this
    # doesn't hurt security. On the other hand it does boost performance
    # a lot!
    SVNPathAuthz on

    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine SVN Repository"

    #read-only access    
    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            Require valid-user
            Allow from localhost
            # Allow from another-ip
            Satisfy any
    </Limit>

    # write access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
            **#Require all denied**
            **Deny from all**
            Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>

    ## for mysql
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine_default;host=localhost"

    RedmineDbUser "redmine"
    RedmineDbPass "SrDQio8BjB0Q"

</Location>
```

Comment: The apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) contained the following:

`[Sat Jun 13 18:33:27.675418 2015] [authn_file:error] [pid 8731] [client 137.110.116.21:41715] AH01619: AuthUserFile not specified in the configuration`

So I had to add the following line to my apache.conf:

`AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd`

You have to touch this file (ie, make sure it exists), or else the error.log will show

`Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/dav_svn1.passwd`

Comment: What link are you referring to?